# Discord.py Fetch Message Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, auto

I want to fetch messages from one private discord channel to my channel. But not all messages. Just my wanted ones. Like "car" message. I want to fetch all "car" messages to my discord channel.
I don't know programming at all. I'm working on it for 2 days :D. It's so easy I think. But i couldn't do it.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(931570478915657790)
    if message.content == "car":
        await channel.send("i found car word!")
```

I just did this :/

Comment: You're likely going to need to read through ALL the history. You can't search the way the client does (which is a lot faster). Are you sure you *really* need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong callback, that callback, '''on_message''' waits until a message is typed to execute. So you kind of have it, but you need to use a different callback.

```
@bot.command()
async def phrase(ctx, days: int = None):
    if days:
        after_date = dt.datetime.utcnow()-dt.timedelta(days=days)
        # limit can be changed to None but that this would make it a slow operation.
        messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=10, oldest_first=True, after=after_date).flatten()
        print(messages)
    else:
        await ctx.send("please enter the number of days wanted")
```

taken from [Discord.py: How to go through channel history and count the occurrences of a phrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524349/discord-py-how-to-go-through-channel-history-and-count-the-occurrences-of-a-phr)
... You then use the messages object to loop over and count the occurrence of desired word

Comment: I don't want the channel history. When someone write "car" message at the moment, I want to get notification. Thats why I use on_message.

Comment: what does printing the channel variable return you

Comment: I'm playing a game called growtopia. In this game people buy cheap items and sell expensive. Like trade. There are lots of discord servers, people sell item here. When I find a cheap item, I just want to get notification :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the channel ID is correct. Also, add an if-statement checking that the message author is not the bot itself. Try this out:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    channel = bot.get_channel(931570478915657790)
    if "car" in message.content:
        await channel.send("i found car word!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the preferred code :

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
channel = bot.get_channel(931570478915657790)
if message.author == bot.user:
    return
if 'car' or 'Car' in message.content:
    await channel.send('i found a car word!')
```

1. Implement a check to see that the word is not in a message from the bot.
2. Check if the required word is present in all of the message content with the  `if 'car' in message.content:`